# Could not locate RPC credentials Error

Tags: bitcoind, windows, bitcoin-cli

I am trying to follow the instructions in the following post:
[Check status of daemon](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46245/check-status-of-daemon)

When I try to run bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo I get the following error:

[image]

When I look for the configuration file. It looks like it is not even there.

I am on Windows.

Comment: Is bitcoind running?

Comment: This was the problem. I had to start the daemon with `bitcoind` first, and then open a new cmd prompt to run `bitcoin-cli get bloackchaininfo`. Please put this as the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: it's "getblockchaininfo" not get blockchaininfo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting this error because bitcoind isn't running. Once it is, it will create an authentication cookie, and bitcoin-cli will be able to connect.

To start bitcoind from cmd prompt, type:

```
cd C:/Program\ Files/Bitcoin/daemon/
```

Press enter, then type:

```
bitcoind
```

And press enter.